# Django: Query with foreign key

Tags: django

I have two models called `Thread` and `Post`. A Thread has `0..*` posts.

Now, I need a query that gets all threads **sorted by the datetime of the latest post in the thread**. In case there is no post yet in the thread, the datetime of the thread creation is important.

Honestly, I am a bit overwhelmed with the database query.

```
Thread:
created_at = DateTimeField()

Post
thread = ForeignKey(Thread)
```

My current approach does not work:

```
newest = Post.objects.filter(thread=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-created_at')
threads = Thread.objects.annotate(
    latest_post=Case(
        When(Exists(Subquery(newest.values_list('created_at')[:1])),
             then=Value(Subquery(
                newest.values_list('created_at')[:1]),
            ),
            default=Value(Thread.created_at)))).order_by('-latest_post')
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can annotate these with the [**`Max`** aggregate [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#max), and use the [**`Coalesce`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) as a fallback mechanism, like:

```
from django.db.models import Max
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Thread.objects.annotate(
    latest_post=Coalesce(Max('post__created_at'), 'created_at')
).order_by('-latest_post')
```

The `latest_post` is thus the timestamp of the maximum `created_at` of the *related* `Post` objects. In case there are no related `Post` objects, we fallback on the `created_at` field of the `Thread`.

Comment: It works! How did you do that so fast? You must be a genius!

Comment: @Aliquis: it is just practicing with annotates/aggregates :)